# How to create a singleton of external Class with vaadin CDI

Tags: java, vaadin, cdi, code-injection

I'm trying to create a session singleton of Eventbus from google commons, into my root UI with vaadin CDI.

There is a way by creating a class extending Eventbus and then Inject it everywhere under Cdi scopes.

```
@SessionScoped
class CDIEventBus extends EventBus {}
```

But I woud prefer to create it with a simple annotation on a field, into my root UI class, like

```
@Produces
Eventbus bus;
```

I also tried it but I have a nullPointerException when I try to access this variable.. Idk if it's possible to find something like a binder where I can add a single instance to the "Injector" e.g

> binder.bind(EventBus.class).asEagerSingleton();

or inject it at Runtime..

Comment: Does this help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138321/using-cdi-in-a-singleton-pattern

Comment: not really, nobody can help me, I'm using a plugin from vaadin..